# D6 Insert module with CKeditor does not work with styles

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, media, javascript

Summary

Using [Imagefield](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield) and  the [Insert modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert), I can insert into [CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) "Automatic" image styles, but not "Lightbox" styles.

What I've tried

This suggests that CKeditor is filtering the inserted code. I've tried disabling (a)  Security>Security filters "HTML filter" (b) Advanced content filter (c) Advanced options>Custom JavaScript configuration "config.allowedContent = true;"

How to

I've added an imagefield to my content type. In Create node, I upload an image, and a Style box appears with "Automatic" and pre-defined imagecache options. If I select Automatic and click  the Insert button, my image appears in CKeditor. If I select one of the imagecache/lightbox options and click Insert, nothing happens.

Set-up

I'm running: Drupal 6.35, CKeditor 1.15 (with CK editor 4.3.4), Insert 1.2, ImageField 3.11, imagecache 2.0-rc1, Lightbox 1.11.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think I have narrowed the problem down to an issue with Lightbox2. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2470898